# Use string comparisons to split a column in R

Tags: regex, r

To the best of my search this question hasn't been asked before.
I have a dataframe column called Product. This column has the company name as well as product model in just one column.

```
product.df <- data.frame("Product" = c("Company1 123M UG", "Company1 234M-I", "Company2 763-87-U","Company2 777-87", "Company3 Name1 87M", "Company3 Name1 O77M", "Company3 Name1 765-U MP"))
```

I want to split out the company names and product model number from this single column into two columns. I need a function that can find similar words between rows and classify them as Company names and the rest of the letters as product model number. No two rows as far as i can tell have same model numbers. So in the case above. I would get this answer

```
new.product.df <- data.frame("CompanyName" = c("Company1", "Company1", "Company2","Company2", "Company3 Name1", "Company3 Name1", "Company3 Name1"), "Model" = c("123M UG", "234M-I", "763-87-U", "777-87", "87M", "O77M", "765-U MP"))
```

I need a function that can compare two strings and return me similar continuous letters and dissimilar letters.

Comment: What does *"compare two strings and return me similar continuous letters and dissimilar letters"*? Please give an example. You want to both extract the  model names/numbers, and do the comparison? Which? What is your expected output for *"Company3 Name1 87M"*? Is it *"Name1 87M"*, *"1 87M"* or *"87M"*?

Comment: How can one know if `Name1` is part of the company name or the beginning of the model name?

Comment: Saying *"split out company names and product model number from this single column into two columns"* is very unclear - which column does the  product name *"Name1"* go in? You really need to give examples.

Comment: Company name can be anything - mixture of letters numbers and spaces, unless the product name has some structure, this question can't be fully solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you're guaranteed the first word is always a company name, then simply do a fixed split on the first space with max 2 output:

```
require(stringi)
stri_split_fixed(product.pd[,1], ' ', n=2)
```

or:

```
apply(product.df, 2, function(...) { stri_split_fixed(..., ' ', n=2) } )

[1] "Company1" "123M UG" 
[1] "Company1" "234M-I"  
[1] "Company2" "763-87-U"
[1] "Company2" "777-87"  
[1] "Company3" "Name1 87M"
[1] "Company3" "Name1 O77M"
[1] "Company3" "Name1 765-U MP"
```

Comment: To the downvoter, this is a correct answer. Please explain what your disagreement with it is?

Comment: This is not his desired output (btw, I didn't downvote). The `Name1` part should stay on the first column.

Comment: @nicola : if you believe you understand *"split out company names and product model number from this single column into two columns"* clearly, then tell us what it means? Which column does the  product name *"Name1"* go in? OP really needs to give examples.

Comment: I really don't know how he wants to split (I also tried to ask him); on the other hand, he provided in the OP his desired output. I just pointed out that your output (as reasonable as it can be) does not match with his `new.product.df`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
new.product.df <- data.frame(company=
    unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(product.df$Product), split=" .[0-9]"), function(x) x[1])), 
    name = 
    unlist(lapply(strsplit(as.character(product.df$Product), split="[1|2] "), function(x) x[2]))
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

according to your data the separator between company and product is the first `space` character , so the first step we need to convert this first `space` character to something else , in this example to `__` , later I'll tell you why we need to do this .

this is your actual data

```
             Product
1        Company1 123M UG
2         Company1 234M-I
3       Company2 763-87-U
4         Company2 777-87
5      Company3 Name1 87M
6     Company3 Name1 O77M
7 Company3 Name1 765-U MP
```

this code to do this kind of conversion

```
product.df$Product <- sub(product.df$Product , pattern = " " , replacement = "__" ,
perl = T)
```

the data should be something like this

```
               Product
1        Company1__123M UG
2         Company1__234M-I
3       Company2__763-87-U
4         Company2__777-87
5      Company3__Name1 87M
6     Company3__Name1 O77M
7   Company3__Name1 765-U MP
```

then use the `tidyr` library to separate this new data frame

```
library("tidyr")
new.product.df <- separate( product.df , Product , c("Company" , "Model") , sep = "__")
```

the reason behind converting `space` character to `__` is that company name also may include `space` character like companies `123M UG` & `Name1 87M` this will cause error later so the first step in this solution is to avoid this later when separating the column.

of course it will be better if we separated on the first occurrence of `space` character , but I don't know how because the global modifier is turned on by default for separator regex , so any suggestions are welcome